# Does a time-varying magnetic field ALWAYS produce an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields

Assume two similar point charges located a distance $\Delta y$ away from each other are set in motion with the same velocity $v$ in opposite directions as shown in the figure. The lab observer located at point $O$ in the mid-way between the charges detects no electric field (the electric field vectors cancel out each other, that is) but a magnetic one complying with:

$$B_z=2\frac{v}{c^2} E_y \space,$$

where $E_y$ is the transverse component of the electric field of each moving charge at point $O$, which is equal to:

$$E_y=\frac{q\gamma (\Delta y/2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0 [{\gamma^2}v^2t^2+(\Delta y/2)^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}} \space,$$

where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. The magnetic field at point $O$ is thus calculated to be:

$$B_z=\frac{qv\gamma (\Delta y/2)}{2\pi c^2 \epsilon_0 [{\gamma^2}v^2t^2+(\Delta y/2)^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}} \space.$$

[image: Figure]

However, observer $O$ claims that the above magnetic field is reduced at his place as time passes by and the charges recede from him. Does this time-varying magnetic field produce a non-zero electric field at point $O$? If so, is there any relation between the so-called non-zero electric field and the Coulomb field of the moving charges at $O$? Remember that the net Coulomb (electric) field is zero at $O$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation seems to be correct. The magnetic field is not zero at $O$. Your calculation shows this perfectly. 
The answer to the question weather there is a nonzero electric field at $O$ is no, eventhough there is a changing Magnetic field.
If we only look at one particle we can build the electromagnetic Tensor in this inertial frame of refrence: 
\begin{equation}
F^{\mu \nu}=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}                                
0 & -E_x/c & -E_y/c & -E_z/c \\                                               
E_x/c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\                                               
E_y/c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
E_z/c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\                                            
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
We know transform into the frame of $O$ we obtain the corresponding electric and magnetic fields. Also $E^i = \frac{qx^i}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^3}$.
\begin{equation}
F^{\mu \nu}_O = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\sigma} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\rho} F^{\sigma \rho}
\end{equation}
If you calculate all off this you all components of $E^i$ and $B_i$. 
\begin{equation}
E^i = \left( E^{\prime}_x, \gamma E^{\prime}_y, \gamma E^{\prime}_z\right)  
\end{equation}
With 
\begin{equation}
E^{\prime i} = \frac{q \gamma }{4\pi \epsilon_0 (\gamma^2 v^2 t^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} \left(- \gamma vt, y, 0\right)
\end{equation}
As you can see, there is only one factor that depends on the direction of the transformation ($y$, $v$) all others are invariant (meaning if you change the sign, r is obviously not invariant under Lorentz transformation). While in the equation for $B_i$ both $v^i$ and $x^i$ are dependent on the direction. If you now concidder both charges with opposite $y$ and $v$ and add the two fields you will get zero at $O$.

And yes a time-variying magnetic field always produce an electric field. But not at all points the field is non zero. Think off a standing electromagnetic wave.

I hope it's correct and I was able to help

Comment: Excellent first answer! Welcome to SE,  @tomtom1-4